# Erro em MySQL - Stored Procedures

Tags: php, laravel, mysql

Estou criando essa procedure para rodar uma vez ao dia, como não tenho experiência, obtive um erro no código abaixo:

```
    CREATE (definer omitido) PROCEDURE `MULTAOFF`()
    BEGIN 


    set @multado = (select `CPFAluno` from multa where `dataMultaFim` <= 
    CURDATE());

    update aluno set `StatusAluno` = '0' where @multado IN (`CPF`) and 
    StatusAluno = '2';

    END
```

Como resultado ao chamar `Call MULTAOFF();` tenho o seguinte erro:

```
Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

O que está acontecendo e como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Você está tentando dar update em StatusAluno, mas também está indicando que a cláusula WHERE pegue o StatusAluno  o update onde o CPF e o Status do aluno seja 2, portanto não tem como dar update e utilizar where com o mesmo campo. Troque sua cláusula WHERE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu erro esta na sua subquery, portanto tente alterar desta forma sua procedure.

```
CREATE (definer omitido) PROCEDURE `MULTAOFF`()
BEGIN 

UPDATE aluno SET `StatusAluno` = '0' where  CPF and 
StatusAlunos IN (select `CPFAluno` from multa where `dataMultaFim` <= 
CURDATE());

END
```